# Oracle 10g Statement level trigger how can I access the rows that have been affected by the statement level trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a trigger and I need to use a statement level trigger.  Now when doing so I need to somehow access the rows that have been affected by this trigger.  My question is can I access something similar the Inserted and Updated tables that MSSQL uses, or does anyone have any other way in which I could achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO If you need to access the row's values, you really need a `for each row` trigger.  SQLServer `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables exists because there's no per-row triggers in that database, and there´s no `updated` pseudo table.  Can you elaborate on why do you need to access individual row values in a statement trigger?

Comment: @jachguate hey thanks for the response.  Basically I need a statement level trigger to fire because we are inserting x number of rows.  I then need to insert one row into another table with values from the first affected row of the statement level trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need multiple triggers (or a compound trigger in 11g with row-level and statement-level sections).  In a row-level trigger, you would see the row that was changed and place some data (a primary key, the ROWID, or the entire row depending on your needs) in either a temporary table, a collection defined in a package, or in a collection defined in your compound trigger.  In your statement-level trigger, you would iterate over the rows that your row-level trigger just identified.  Personally, I'd also tend to create a before statement trigger that initialized the collection just in case there was still data in whatever structure you're maintaining when the statement is first executed).